# Create multiple proxies on the same server subnet

Tags: networking, proxy

How to place multiple proxies on the same subnet using the same port?

For example:

**.**.***.13:8000

**.**.***.14:8000

**.**.***.15:8000

The server is on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.